# How to specify environment dependencies in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Where does one list the environment variable dependencies for a Rails application?

I don't want the app to run if the user hasn't specified the variables or at a minimum output some form of notice that says ***Don't run until you've set the following environment variables..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd put something like that in [`config/boot.rb`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#config-boot-rb):

```
# usual boot.rb stuff...
raise 'Set PANCAKES in your environment!' unless ENV.has_key? 'PANCAKES'
```

The nice thing about `boot.rb` is that it is run very early in the start up process so you don't have to wait for all the Rails machinery to start (which can take a long time) before you know there's a problem.